# How to import a javascript module with JSX, in browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, module, jsx

I have a directory with the following structure, as part of a React project.

- index.html
- main.js
- mod.js

In the HTML, I use script tags to get React and Babel since my JS files contain JSX.
I also use a script tag to include my main.js file, like so:
`<script type="text/babel" src="main.js"></script>`

I found out that I had to use `type=text/babel` to have the JSX processed correctly.

mod.js is a module that I want to import. in main.js
I use:

`import {mod_func} from './mod'`

and in mod.js I use `export mod_func function()...`

However, when I open the HTML in a browser through a web server (Web Server for Chrome), I get:
**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

After reading a bit about this error, I thought that I need to have the HTML treat my main.js as a module that can import other modules, by using the `type="module"` tag, but I also need the `type=text/babel` tag, so I'm not sure what to do.

How can I import javascript modules that contain JSX when I can only set the script type as one of those types?

Comment: Set up this to do it all for you: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app

Comment: *"How can I import javascript modules that contain JSX when I can only set the script type as one of those types?"* You usually have a build process convert JSX files to JS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSX` stands for `JavaScript` Syntax Extension and is commonly used in `ReactJS Apps` . If I look a bit deeper into the JSX files, It allows you to store `html-xml-styled codes` into a JavaScript Variable and you can utilize a function to return an `HTML-XML-styled code`. in addition, you need babel to do it as a `transpiler` since your browser doesn't have any clue about your code coming as  a `JSX` file.

The error you got faced with was about the two approaches of using node modules in JavaScript World.

```
1. ES6 Module [ you use require ] 
2. CommonJS  [ you use import ]
```

**Hint**: If you're mad keen on using `JSX` as a file format for your app, make use of

**`npx create-react-app [your project's name]`**

or

**`npx create-react-app --template [ template's name ]`**

or

Use **`Webpack`** as a **bundler** and **`babel`** files to do the same thing **[ Advanced Mode ]**

**Hint**: You can find a lot of **React templates** in **`npm packages`**

**Todo:**
Two approaches to export [ **Default export** / **Name export** ]

**Name export :** `export const [ name ]  = . . . .`

- **Hint**: You need **`a curly brace`** to import it

**Default export:** `export default . . .`

- **Hint**: You don't need **`a curly brace`** at all to import it